# which the best best technique of String equals comparing

Tags: java

which if block is better?

```
private static void checkStr(String str) {

    if (str.equals("exit")) {
        System.out.println("It is equal");
    }
    if ("exit".equals(str)) {
        System.out.println("It is equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you doing it for development i will suggest to go with ApacheCommon much better elegant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the first approach you are giving margin to `NullPointerExceptions`. So from my point of view the second one is better.

For the case of constants you should prefer always the second approach over the first one.

```
"exit".equals(str)
```

You can find a detailed explanation [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java-best-practices/constant-value-should-always-come-first-in-comparison/)

---

I personally prefer another approach. [Apache Commons - commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) have `ObjectUtils.equals(Object, Object)`. With this approach you are always safe even with **null** values.

From [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> Compares two objects for equality, where either one or both objects
>   may be null.
>
> ```
>  ObjectUtils.equals(null, null)                  = true
>  ObjectUtils.equals(null, "")                    = false
>  ObjectUtils.equals("", null)                    = false
>  ObjectUtils.equals("", "")                      = true
>  ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, null)          = false
>  ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, "true")        = false
>  ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE)  = true
>  ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE) = false
> ```

Comment: To be sure, this is only true if you want to allow nulls.  In many cases, you _want_ to throw up on nulls as soon as possible, because they represent a bug you'll want to fix.

Comment: Thanks. You described the solution in nice way.

Answer (score 2):

I think `str.equals("exit")` is the more natural way to write the comparison, but would throw a `NullPointerException` if `str` is null, whereas `"exit".equals(str)` would simply evaluate to false.

You need to know why `str` can be null though. A null value could be caused by a bug or error elsewhere in the program, for example so you may be better checking for `null` separately instead of ignoring it, or making sure that it isn't null beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer:

```
"exit".equals(str)
```

just to avoid `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

You will **duck** `NullPointerException` case using:

```
"exit".equals(str)
```